# App id does not exit - IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

The app is first uploaded by my colleague using `ionic upload`. When I am trying to upload the same app I am getting the following error.

```
An error occurred uploading the build: An error occurred uploading your application - App ID 4af0u3f5 does not exist

An error occurred uploading your application - App ID 4af0u3f5 does not exist (CLI v1.7.15)
```

What I assuming that I am getting this error because we both have different play store id and one app id can be associate with one unique email id.

Is there any way that we can work and upload the app by having two different play store id.

Answer (score 0):

This should not have anything to do with your play store id's.

This is all to do with the `ionic.io` login that the both of you use.

Let's presume that you both use the same code that you have hosted on some code versioning system, and let's say that he committed and pushed all the changes to the server after he used the `ionic upload` command.

In that case, you downloaded all his changes and, this is the crucial part, before you do the actual `ionic upload` command you need to login (`ionic login`) with the same credentials as he used (email/password). And these should be the credentials to the `ionic.io` service.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this. The person who upload the app first, he need to share the app with other. In that way the who receive the share invite can also upload the share app.

All we have to do is.

```
ionic share <emailid>
```

After that share invite would go to the person and he can accept the invite. After accepting the invite the same app id will be added to his ionic account.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same because l had mistakenly deleted the app from ionic view. i fixed it by deleting .io-config.json and deleting the app id from ionic.config.json to be like { "name": "{{AppName}}", "app_id": "", "v2": true, "typescript": true }

Then l tried to upload again.